# Connected components labeling in GraphicsMagick?

Tags: graphicsmagick

Is there a way to scan the image pixel by pixel and print the coordinates of each pixel regions by color? similiar to this ImageMagick´s feature [Uniquely Label Connected Regions](https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php). I'd like to do it in bash or python to identify the coordinates of several rectangles inside an image, each rectangle is of different color or has a border line of some color.

Example how this can be done in ImageMagick.

```
magick objects.gif -connected-components 4 -auto-level -depth 8 objects.png

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 256x171+0+0 119.2,80.8 33117 srgb(0,0,0)
  2: 120x135+104+18 159.5,106.5 8690 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 50x36+129+44 154.2,63.4 1529 srgb(0,0,0)
  4: 21x23+0+45 8.8,55.9 409 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 4x10+252+0 253.9,4.1 31 srgb(255,255,255)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621

Comment: Thanks for answer.